# Compare JSON data in code behind vb.net

Tags: json, vb.net

I have two text files that have JSON data. I want to combine these two JSON objects into one based on a particular property. I want to do this in code-behind file in vb.net.

Any help appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: I don't know how to start.. I have a basic idea of how to do.. First get the data from files, then compare and merge data

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask